# Understanding the role of 將 in a sentence

Tags: meaning

I was trying to write a short text about 姜子牙。Due to my limited success, I searched for Chinese materials and found a folktale [here](https://zh.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A4%AA%E5%85%AC%E6%9C%9B). It says:

> 周文王請呂尚上車，屏退拉車手，親自將姜尚請回都城

My problem is with the last part. Is the 將 here the written equivalent of 把，or is it something different, because a 把 feels superfluous. Is it just a reformulation of:

> 周文王親自請姜子牙與他回都城

or is there any special meaning?

Comment: equivalent of 把 ✓，omitting 把/将 would mean "fronting" the object 姜尚which generally speaking seems possible, but in this case it may have to be moved in front of the whole predicate including the adverb 親自:  姜尚親自請回都城

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the 將 here the written equivalent of 把

Yes, and it's more formal than 把. According to the context, especially "屏退拉車手", "親自將姜尚請回都城" indicates that "周文王" pulled the cart by himself; while "周文王親自請姜子牙與他回都城" doesn't have such intent strongly. With the usage of "將" (or "把"), the object of the action, "姜尚" (and then the action, "親自拉車") gets emphasized.